# Set property/value across all sculpt brushes?

Tags: sculpting, blend-files, settings, brushes

I have purchased a set of 80+ sculpting brushes. Their quality is degraded (distortion) because the falloff is set to "Smooth" instead of "Constant," and their strength value is also set too high, while hardness is too low.

Is there any way (within or outside of Blender) I can adjust these values on all the brushes all at once? I would then save them through the Brush Manager addon.

Doing larger batches would save me a lot of time.